# MongoDb Aggregation toDate() in Spring Data Mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to recreate an aggregation pipeline I built in mongo compass in Java. It consists of an $addFields which converts string to date using $toDate. I am trying to do the same in Java with Spring Data Mongo Aggregation Pipeline but have failed thus far and need help

I tried with some other example with date from string and projection but I don't know how to work it with $addFields.

This is the mongo pipeline that I need to be recreated in Java with Spring Data.

```
{
    "event.currentTimeStamp": {
        "$toDate": "$event.timestamp"
    }
}
```

This works fine from shell and Compass.

This is my sample Document .

```
{
    "_id":"5c0f0f97ece8cc0009c0a8f8",
    "event":{
    "jobid":"e4955ab0-003a-40fd-ac5a-4363c3e0f604",
    "username":"sn",
    "timestamp":"Mon Dec 10 20:15:02 EST 2018",
    "system":"Mercury",
    "eventStatus":"START",
    "eventType":"UPLOAD"
}
```

I need the timestamp field to be converted to date and added as a field so that I can do other aggregation operations on them.

NOTE: Hoping to get an answer as a form of aggregation as that's what I am doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below answer. Hope this will help you.

```
db.getCollection('test1').aggregate([
{$addFields : {"date" : {"$toDate" : "$event.timestamp"}}}
])
```